# Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

For any function, given an interval with closed/open brackets, does a function have to have a min and max for the Extreme Value Theorem to apply? For example, does the extreme value theorem apply for the function f(x) = |x|?

In my opinion, I believe not because this function doesn't have a discrete maximum value. Is this thinking correct?

In addition, if at some point of any function is discontinuous within a interval, does it automatically mean that the application of the EVT is invalid? For example, take a simple floor function, since it's not continous, then it doesn't apply.

Comment: You should recheck the your statement of the EVT as it only applies to continuous function (not the floor function) in a closed and bounded interval.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I didn't add my past part in @Bcpicao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EVT applies exactly when the hypothesis I mentioned in my comment exist, and there is no redundancy, meaning all of them must apply in order for the theorem to work. Importantly, it has nothing to do with differentiability.

$f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$  is indeed continuous so, pick a bounded, closed interval (say, $[a,b]$) then indeed, the EVT applies. Namely, the extreme values are $0$ if $ab<0$ or $min(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)$ else, for the minimum; $max(\lvert a\rvert,\lvert b\rvert)$ for the maximum.

Again, for a discontinuous function such as the floor function the EVT does not apply, which doesn't mean that, by chance, the extreme values are not attained, which indeed they are, for any bounded interval.

Comment: Say, if the boundaries were -infinity, to infinity. Then it wouldn't apply seeing what you have said.

Comment: SORRY, I meant |x| wouldn't apply over the range of negative inf to inf

Comment: Again, $\mathbb{R}=]-\infty:\infty[$ is not a bounded interval, so no, the EVT does not apply. Although, that does NOT mean $f(x)$ doesn't attain its extreme values, think about any constant function or $cos(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry again, say if you have a constant function F(x) = 4, from what you are saying now that between [1, 3]. ECT would apply? I'm just trying to understand is all. This is because this function is continuous within this interval. In short, I think the real question, I'm asking no matter what function we are looking at, if the function is continuous within an interval, then EVT Applies, right?

Comment: @KoOpwam I'm afraid I don't understand your confusion. Think of the EVT as a ruler, and you want to check that a line is $10$cm long with it: great tool for the job. But, if you're in a pitch black room, it is useless as you cannot see the marks on it. But you do agree that just because you can't use the ruler in a dark room, it does not mean that the line isn't $10$cm long, just means you don't know it beforehand. It's the same here, without the hypothesis, the EVT is a ruler in a dark room. The last example you gave is of a continuous function in a bounded interval so the lights are up!

Comment: Ahhh ok. I get it now. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, by your first commmet in this thread, you meant -inf to inf as the interval right?